# I want to remove degree centigrade notation and brackets

Tags: pandas

What code do I use?

This is the data.

```
    January February    March   April   May June    July    August  September   October November    December
Parameter                                               
Avg. Temperature °C 22.5 °C 23.5 °C 23.8 °C 23.4 °C 23.4 °C 22.5 °C 21.8 °C 22.1 °C 23.1 °C 23.3 °C 21.6 °C 21.6 °C
Avg. Temperature °F (72.5) °F   (74.3) °F   (74.8) °F   (74.1) °F   (74.1) °F   (72.5) °F   (71.2) °F   (71.7) °F   (73.5) °F   (74) °F (70.8) °F   (70.9) °F
```

Using astype(float) is giving the following error : ValueError: could not convert string to float: '22.5 °C'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) per all columns for get floats or integers, last convert values to floats:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.extract(r'(\d+\.\d+|\d+)', expand=False)).astype(float)
print (df)
                                  January  February  March  April  May June  \
Avg. Temperature °C 22.5 °C          23.5      23.8   23.4   23.4      22.5   
Avg. Temperature °F (72.5) °F        74.3      74.8   74.1   74.1      72.5   

                                July  August  September  October  November  \
Avg. Temperature °C 22.5 °C     21.8    22.1       23.1     23.3      21.6   
Avg. Temperature °F (72.5) °F   71.2    71.7       73.5     74.0      70.8   

                               December  
Avg. Temperature °C 22.5 °C        21.6  
Avg. Temperature °F (72.5) °F      70.9
```

Comment: Worked. Unfortunately, there were some rows with float. It has returned to *Nan*. 
 Original data part:

Max. Temperature °F (83) °F (85.3) °F (85.3) °F (83.9) °F (84.2) °F (82.7) °F (81.4) °F (82.3) °F (85) °F (84.4) °F (79.4) °F (80.3) °F
Precipitation / Rainfall mm 45 27 49 82 54 33 43 43 31 59 108 63

Result part:
Max. Temperature °F 83.0 85.3 85.3 83.9 84.2 82.7 81.4 82.3 85.0 84.4 79.4 80.3
Precipitation / Rainfall mm NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN

Comment: @BernardNgoruse then use `df = df.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.str.extract(r'(\d+\.\d+|\d+)', expand=False)).astype(float)`